# Selecting all objects in a json array that meet criteria in mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I need to capture rows when data inside a json field in mysql meets certain criteria. What select would I run to get the rows returned where the json column had a Status value of 1000 in any object in the array?

I tried using the something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Task_JSON->"$[0]" = 1000;
```

I'm using Server version: 5.7.11 of mysql

```
[
{
 "Sequence":"1" ,
 "Status":"1000" 
},
{
 "Sequence":"2" ,
 "Status":"1000" 
},
{
 "Sequence":"3" ,
 "Status":"3000"
}
]
```

Comment: The JSON example value you gave, is that for single field in a row?

Comment: Yes. The object is held in a single field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution using [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(Task_JSON, '{"Status":"1000"}') > 0;
```

Another solution using [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(Task_JSON, 'one', '1000', NULL, '$[*]."Status"') IS NOT NULL;
```

> **demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3JTQreVi63FS7HbmWQ9TEM/4

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Task_JSON ->>'Status' = 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON_EXTRACT can help you.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html

```
select * from table  where JSON_EXTRACT(Task_JSON, '$.Status') = 1000 ;
```

Comment: Received this error
#3141 - Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_extract: "Invalid value." at position 308 

I am using mysql version 5.6. Your referencing the version 8 in your link.